# Using dplyr::lag to tidy data frame and fill variables

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning

I'm trying to clean my data so that every row directly beneath a row that contains "gamecentre-playbyplay-event" is labeled as a goal, every row that contains "gamecentre-playbyplay-event" directly beneath a "goal" row is labeled primary assist, and every row that contains "gamecentre-playbyplay-event" directly beneath a "primary assist" row is labeled secondary assist.

Here's what the data looks like:

```
mydata

# A tibble: 15 x 1
   value                                                                                 
   <chr>                                                                                 
 1 "<div class=\"gamecentre-playbyplay-event team-border--lhjmq-bat gamecentre-playby"   
 2 "<a href=\"/players/14695\" class=\"gamecentre__link gamecentre__link--goal\" data-re"
 3 "<a href=\"/players/16639\" class=\"gamecentre__link gamecentre__link--goal\" data-re"
 4 "<a href=\"/players/17027\" class=\"gamecentre__link gamecentre__link--goal\" data-re"
 5 "<div class=\"gamecentre-playbyplay-event team-border--lhjmq-mon gamecentre-playby"   
 6 "<a href=\"/players/17453\" class=\"gamecentre__link gamecentre__link--goal\" data-re"
 7 "<a href=\"/players/14639\" class=\"gamecentre__link gamecentre__link--goal\" data-re"
 8 "<div class=\"gamecentre-playbyplay-event team-border--lhjmq-mon gamecentre-playby"   
 9 "<a href=\"/players/18061\" class=\"gamecentre__link gamecentre__link--goal\" data-re"
10 "<a href=\"/players/14752\" class=\"gamecentre__link gamecentre__link--goal\" data-re"
11 "<a href=\"/players/17522\" class=\"gamecentre__link gamecentre__link--goal\" data-re"
12 "<div class=\"gamecentre-playbyplay-event team-border--lhjmq-mon gamecentre-playby"   
13 "<a href=\"/players/14752\" class=\"gamecentre__link gamecentre__link--goal\" data-re"
14 "<a href=\"/players/14639\" class=\"gamecentre__link gamecentre__link--goal\" data-re"
15 "<a href=\"/players/14757\" class=\"gamecentre__link gamecentre__link--goal\" data-re"
```

There are a few problems here though.

1. I need to set conditions so that the rows are correctly labeled.
2. If there is no "secondary assist" row, the row is labeled as an `NA`.
3. If there is no "primary assist" row, the row is also labeled as an `NA`.

I'm trying to use `dplyr::lag()` for this, but me wanting `NA`s when there aren't primary or secondary assists is confusing.

Here's the basis of what I have so far:

```
goals <- mydata %>%
  filter(dplyr::lag(str_detect(value, "gamecentre-playbyplay-event team-border"), 1))

goals

# A tibble: 4 x 1
  value                                                                                                                                
  <chr>                                                                                                                                
1 "<a href=\"/players/14695\" class=\"gamecentre__link gamecentre__link--goal\" data-re
2 "<a href=\"/players/17453\" class=\"gamecentre__link gamecentre__link--goal\" data-re
3 "<a href=\"/players/18061\" class=\"gamecentre__link gamecentre__link--goal\" data-re
4 "<a href=\"/players/14752\" class=\"gamecentre__link gamecentre__link--goal\" data-re
```

And here's what I'd want my data to look like at the end of all of this. I think using `dplyr::lag()` is the way to go, but I'm not sure.

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  goal                                     primary_assist                                secondary_assist                              
  <chr>                                    <chr>                                         <chr>                                         
1 "<a href=\"/players/14695\" class=\"gam~ "<a href=\"/players/16639\" class=\"gamecent~ "<a href=\"/players/17027\" class=\"gamecentr~
2 "<a href=\"/players/17453\" class=\"gam~ "<a href=\"/players/14639\" class=\"gamecent~ NA                                            
3 "<a href=\"/players/18061\" class=\"gam~ "<a href=\"/players/14752\" class=\"gamecent~ "<a href=\"/players/17522\" class=\"gamecentr~
4 "<a href=\"/players/14752\" class=\"gam~ "<a href=\"/players/14639\" class=\"gamecent~ "<a href=\"/players/14757\" class=\"gamecentr~
```

Any ideas?

dput:

```
    mydata <- structure(list(value = c("<div class=\"gamecentre-playbyplay-event team-border--lhjmq-bat gamecentre-playby", 
"<a href=\"/players/14695\" class=\"gamecentre__link gamecentre__link--goal\" data-re", 
"<a href=\"/players/16639\" class=\"gamecentre__link gamecentre__link--goal\" data-re", 
"<a href=\"/players/17027\" class=\"gamecentre__link gamecentre__link--goal\" data-re", 
"<div class=\"gamecentre-playbyplay-event team-border--lhjmq-mon gamecentre-playby", 
"<a href=\"/players/17453\" class=\"gamecentre__link gamecentre__link--goal\" data-re", 
"<a href=\"/players/14639\" class=\"gamecentre__link gamecentre__link--goal\" data-re", 
"<div class=\"gamecentre-playbyplay-event team-border--lhjmq-mon gamecentre-playby", 
"<a href=\"/players/18061\" class=\"gamecentre__link gamecentre__link--goal\" data-re", 
"<a href=\"/players/14752\" class=\"gamecentre__link gamecentre__link--goal\" data-re", 
"<a href=\"/players/17522\" class=\"gamecentre__link gamecentre__link--goal\" data-re", 
"<div class=\"gamecentre-playbyplay-event team-border--lhjmq-mon gamecentre-playby", 
"<a href=\"/players/14752\" class=\"gamecentre__link gamecentre__link--goal\" data-re", 
"<a href=\"/players/14639\" class=\"gamecentre__link gamecentre__link--goal\" data-re", 
"<a href=\"/players/14757\" class=\"gamecentre__link gamecentre__link--goal\" data-re"
)), .Names = "value", class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

Comment: What if you have multiple secondary assists?

Comment: It wouldn't be possible. The example I gave is pretty good for handling edge cases. A maximum of 1 goal/primary assist/secondary assist per goal, though it's possible for there to be no primary assists or secondary assists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option would be to create a grouping variable and then `spread`

```
library(tidyverse)
mydata %>%
   #create a group based on the occurrence of 'playby'
   group_by(grp = cumsum(str_detect(value, 'playby'))) %>% 
   # filter out the first row of the group that have playby
   filter(row_number() > 1) %>% 
   # create a new category column
   mutate(categ = c("goal", "primary_assist", "secondary_assist")[row_number()]) %>%
   # spread from long to wide
   spread(categ, value) %>% 
   # remove the grouping column as part of clean up
   ungroup %>% 
   select(-grp)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  goal                                   primary_assist                              secondary_assist                           
#  <chr>                                  <chr>                                       <chr>                                      
#1 "<a href=\"/players/14695\" class=\"g… "<a href=\"/players/16639\" class=\"gamece… "<a href=\"/players/17027\" class=\"gamece…
#2 "<a href=\"/players/17453\" class=\"g… "<a href=\"/players/14639\" class=\"gamece… <NA>                                       
#3 "<a href=\"/players/18061\" class=\"g… "<a href=\"/players/14752\" class=\"gamece… "<a href=\"/players/17522\" class=\"gamece…
#4 "<a href=\"/players/14752\" class=\"g… "<a href=\"/players/14639\" class=\"gamece… "<a href=\"/players/14757\" class=\"gamece…
```

Comment: **Beautiful** use of `str_detect()` in the grouping.

Comment: Fantastic answer. Really appreciate it.